# Convert Double to Decimal in LinQ Query

Tags: linq, silverlight, service, ria

im doing a LinQ query in C# , but im getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Casting to Decimal is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities queries, because the required precision and scale information
>   cannot be inferred.

Recently I created a RIA Services in my Lightswitch Application, and I want to get a simple operation.

```
public class Reporte_HorasporCliente
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Cliente { get; set; }
    public double HPD { get; set; }
    public double? HPG { get; set; }
    public double? HAP { get; set; }
    public double? HCL { get; set; }
    public double? HEP { get; set; }
    public double? HEJ { get; set; }
    public double? HFT { get; set; }
    public double? HPP { get; set; }
    public double? Saldo { get; set; }
    public decimal? Cumplimiento { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaOrden { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<Reporte_HorasporCliente> getReporteHrsCliente()
    {
        var query = from q in this.Context.DetalleOrdenCompras
                    select new Reporte_HorasporCliente
                    {
                        ID = q.Id,
                        Cliente = q.OrdenCompra.Cliente.Nombre,
                        HAP = q.HAP,
                        HCL = q.HCL,
                        HEJ = q.HEJ,
                        HEP = q.HEP,
                        HFT = q.HFT,
                        HPD = q.HPD,
                        HPG = q.HPG,
                        HPP = q.HPD - q.HPG,
                        Saldo = q.HPD - q.HEJ,
                        FechaOrden = q.OrdenCompra.FechaOrden,
                        Cumplimiento = (q.HEJ == 0 ? 0 : ((q.HPD / q.HEJ) * 10) / 100),
                    };
        return query;
    }
```

> HEJ and HPD are double.

In "Cumplimiento" im doing:

```
Cumplimiento = (decimal)(q.HEJ == 0 ? 0 : ((q.HPD / q.HEJ) * 10) / 100),
Cumplimiento = Convert.ToDecimal((q.HEJ == 0 ? 0 : ((q.HPD / q.HEJ) * 10) / 100)),
Cumplimiento = (q.HEJ == 0 ? 0 : (((decimal)q.HPD / (decimal)q.HEJ) * 10) / 100),
```

Whitout any results, i really need some help, thank you.

Comment: A side note: converting between double and decimal (either direction) is *usually* a bad idea. It suggests that one side or the other has chosen an inappropriate datatype.

Comment: Not even close to an optimal solution, but if you really need it now i would suggest you to try Cumplimiento = Decimal.Parse(q.HEJ == 0 ? 0 : ((q.HPD / q.HEJ) * 10) / 100).ToString())

Comment: Sorry, I missed one bracket. There you go: Cumplimiento = Decimal.Parse((q.HEJ == 0 ? 0 : ((q.HPD / q.HEJ) * 10) / 100).ToString())

Comment: The same error "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for resurrecting an old thread. I ended here via Google, and wanted to give an at least working answer.

As others have noted, this is in general a bad idea and you should not blindly cast between double and decimal. To actually do this, you need to get the data into memory first, as the cast can not be done in sql.

```
public IQueryable<Reporte_HorasporCliente> getReporteHrsCliente()
    {
        var query = (from q in this.Context.DetalleOrdenCompras
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = q.Id,
                        Cliente = q.OrdenCompra.Cliente.Nombre,
                        HAP = q.HAP,
                        HCL = q.HCL,
                        HEJ = q.HEJ,
                        HEP = q.HEP,
                        HFT = q.HFT,
                        HPD = q.HPD,
                        HPG = q.HPG,
                        HPP = q.HPD - q.HPG,
                        Saldo = q.HPD - q.HEJ,
                        FechaOrden = q.OrdenCompra.FechaOrden,
                      }).ToList()
                      .Select(q => new Reporte_HorasporCliente 
                                   {
                        ID = q.ID,
                        Cliente = q.Cliente,
                        HAP = q.HAP,
                        HCL = q.HCL,
                        HEJ = q.HEJ,
                        HEP = q.HEP,
                        HFT = q.HFT,
                        HPD = q.HPD,
                        HPG = q.HPG,
                        HPP = q.HPP,
                        Saldo = q.Saldo,
                        FechaOrden = q.FechaOrden,
                        Cumplimiento = (decimal)((q.HEJ == 0 ? 0 : ((q.HPD / q.HEJ) * 10) / 100)),
                 });
        return query;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

double value cannot be converted into decimal automatically. Use Convert.ToDecimal() method explicitly while assining double value in decimal variable.You should update your code as follows:

```
  var query = from q in this.Context.DetalleOrdenCompras
                select new Reporte_HorasporCliente
                {
                    ID = q.Id,
                    Cliente = q.OrdenCompra.Cliente.Nombre,
                    HAP = q.HAP,
                    HCL = q.HCL,
                    HEJ = q.HEJ,
                    HEP = q.HEP,
                    HFT = q.HFT,
                    HPD = q.HPD,
                    HPG = q.HPG,
                    HPP = q.HPD - q.HPG,
                    Saldo = q.HPD - q.HEJ,
                    FechaOrden = q.OrdenCompra.FechaOrden,
                    Cumplimiento = Convert.ToDecimal( (q.HEJ == 0 ? 0 : ((q.HPD / q.HEJ) * 10) / 100)),
                };
    return query;
```

Comment: I used Cumplimiento = Convert.ToDecimal((q.HEJ == 0 ? 0 : ((q.HPD / q.HEJ) * 10) / 100)), without any results, the same error is showing.